# java - checking the array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Tonight I wrote a code which gets fed with a .txt file which name it gets from the command line argument. it puts each character of the textfile in an array.
this is a sample of these textfiles

```
7 11
###########
#     #   #
#   ###   #
#   #     #
# K ###   #
#     #   #
###########
```

i want to check if it would be possible for K to walk past every single " ", the "#" are walls. So if I check this lvl here it should print false because theres a wall on the right side, while here

```
5 8
########
#  K   #
# ###  #
#      #
########
```

it should be true. this is how far I got (sorry for german variable names and comments):

```
import java.io.*;

public class unbenannt {

    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(args[0]);    //Dateipfad wird übergeben als Kommandozeilenarg.
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String zeile1 = br.readLine();  //Zeile1 wird gelesen für x und y
        String[] xypos = zeile1.split(" ");     

        int hoehe   = Integer.parseInt(xypos[0]); //String=>int
        int laenge  = Integer.parseInt(xypos[1]);

        String[][] spielfeld = new String[hoehe][laenge];   //0. Dim wird Anzahl Zeilen, 1. Dim wird die Länge d. Zeilen aber beides 0-basiert(!)
        //Zeile einlesen.
        String zeile = "";
        int j = 0; //aktuelle zeile
        while (zeile != null) {
            zeile = br.readLine();
            if(zeile != null) {
                //System.out.print(j);
                for(int i=0;i<laenge;i++){ //2. Schleife für Zeile ist j
                    spielfeld[j][i] = String.valueOf(zeile.charAt(i));
                    }
                }
            j = j +1;
        }
         //array ist definiert
        //algorythmus: wenn an feld 2 weiße = true; ausgenommen wandnähe

        String weissfeld =      " ";
        String schwarzfeld =    "#";
        String kassiofeld =     "K";

        //2basiert weil wandproblem:
        //Y-Achse invertiert => -1 in höhe für Norden:

        for(int posy = 2;posy < hoehe-1;posy = posy+1){         
            for(int posx = 2;posx < laenge-1;posx = posx+1){
                if(false == schwarzfeld.equals(spielfeld[posy][posx])){
                    boolean resultN = schwarzfeld.equals(spielfeld[posy][posx-1]);
                    boolean resultO = schwarzfeld.equals(spielfeld[posy+1][posx]);
                    boolean resultS = schwarzfeld.equals(spielfeld[posy][posx+1]);
                    boolean resultW = schwarzfeld.equals(spielfeld[posy-1][posx]);
                    int fehlerzahl = 0;

                    if(resultN==true){
                        fehlerzahl = fehlerzahl+1; //fehlerzahl+1
                    }

                    if(resultO==true){
                        fehlerzahl = fehlerzahl+1; //fehlerzahl+1
                    }

                    if(resultS==true){
                        fehlerzahl = fehlerzahl+1; //fehlerzahl+1

                    }
                    if(resultW==true){
                        fehlerzahl = fehlerzahl+1; //fehlerzahl+1
                    }
                    if(fehlerzahl > 2){
                        System.out.println("Not all white spaces reachable.");
                        break; //
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No error means success. Script finished.");

        br.close();
    }
}
```

my solution was that if every walkable space has 2 other walkable spaces nearby in north east south or west all spaces are accessable. but i would have to make an exception for all the spaces directly at the outer wall because there one field that connects to a space is enough, example

```
5 7
#######
#K    #
# # # #
# # # #
#######
```

this should be true, but its not because the fields on the lower half are just connected to a wall but still theyre accessible.. in my script i dont check the array at index [0][n] and [1][n] aswell as not checking [n][0] && [n][1] so i dont get this error but i would like to.. also a case where my algorithm wouldnt work would be this:

```
8 11
###########
#         #
# ######  #
# #K   #  #
# #    #  #
# ######  #
#         #
###########
```

maybe you got some ideas on how to improve the code.. im a total beginner and only speak java for 2 weeks.. thanks in advance and for reading until down here :)

Comment: your code won't work for mazes with specific properties like the last example. Use flood-fill (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) instead for correct results

Comment: how could i implement that into the code? is there a script to import or would i have to do it myself?

Comment: Flood-fill is a well-known solution for this kind of problem; typing "flood fill" in the SO search box returns over a hundred questions; it should be easy to find one that helps you take the next step in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to implement this, for my answer, I will use a breadth-first traversal of the grid.

```
char [][] grid;
Deque<Point> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
HashSet<Point> visited = new HashSet<>();
int kx; // x coordinate of k
int ky; // y coordinate of k
Point start = new Point(kx, ky);
queue.add(start);

int [] dx = {0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1};
int [] dy = {1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1};
while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
    Point p = queue.poll();
    if (visited.contains(p)) {
        continue;
    }
    visited.add(p);
    for (int i = 0; i < dx.length; i++) {
        int nx = (int)p.getX()+dx[i];
        int ny = (int)p.getY()+dy[i];
        if (validCoordinates(nx, ny) && grid[nx][ny] == ' ')) {
            queue.add(new Point(nx, ny));
        }
    }
}

boolean allReachable = true;
outer: for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
        if (grid[i][j] == ' ' && !visited.contains(new Point(i, j))) {
            allReachable = false;
            break outer;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(allReachable ? "All white spaces are reachable" : "Not all white spaces are reachable");
```

The idea is to start at where k is, visit all adjacent cells that are open, and do that recursively. Each time you visit an open cell, You add it to a set. After you're done visiting possible cells, you loop through the grid, and for each open cell, check if it's in the visited set. If there's at least one open cell that isn't in the visited set, then that means you failed to visit all open cells from the starting position.

BTW, I didn't include the `validCoordinates` method in the implementation, it's simple enough to figure it out on your own. Hope this helps.

Comment: what is the validCoordinates method? I'm sorry I dont even know how to make my own functions... I use the public static void main(String args[]) all the time :<  do I have to import it like I did with java.io.* ? cant find it on the oracle java documentation page :X

Comment: so I tried understanding your code but I already start to have problems with line Deque<Point> queue = new ArrayDeque<>(); ... :( I got your idea but I dont see how you make code out of it. \n I tried to get your code to work by 

import java.*;

public class solution{
 public static void main(String args[]){
 }
}

but it doesnt work

Comment: validCoordinates is a method that would return true if the passed arguments are within the boundaries of the grid. If you don't know how to define your own methods yet, then you can just replace validCoordinates with a check that  0<= nx < grid.length and 0 <= ny < grid[0].length

Comment: Deque is an interface. The ArrayDeque class implements that interface. ArrayDeque is a data structure that behaves like a double ended queue, meaning you can add/remove elements from either side of the queue.